# When trying to change the speed of animation in queue(fadeOut) in jQuery from "slow" to a number "3000" - it's not working

Tags: jquery

I have this code (that works) for animation and fadeOut at the same time:

```
$('#vote').fadeOut({queue: false, duration: 'slow'});
$('#vote').animate({ top: "-10px", left: "25px" }, 'slow');
```

However, if I want to make the animation to be slower, i.e. 3 seconds long, it is not working:

```
$('#vote').fadeOut({queue: false, duration: '3000'});
$('#vote').animate({ top: "-10px", left: "25px" }, '3000');
```

Any idea why is it not accepting the number the same way as the word "slow".

Comment: pass number. not string

Comment: @Mehul Mohan ;D you are right! My bad! So, removing the single quotes around 3000 helped and now it's working. I think I will leave it here, somebody could benefit from the same silly mistake in the future. So, somebody add it as an anser and I will tick it in 10 minutes - I have to wait according to Stackoverflow ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass `3000` instead of `'3000'`

Answer (score 1):

According to the jQuery documentation only `fast` for 200ms and `slow` for 600ms are allowed as string. If you want to pass custom time you have to pass it as Integer.

```
$('#vote').animate({ top: "-10px", left: "25px" }, 3000);
```

Comment: Yeah, btw. the documentation for jQuery is not very clear/well organized. All options should be named right where the option is named, not in the text with examples. It's hard to find quickly - you need to read the whole text to find this simple info.